# "Warning Machine not in commited state"

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, dualboot

I am responsible for an  HP Elite Desk G4 desktop. It has a dual boot configuration with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It works fine except for

> "Warning Machine not in committed state"

message while starting up. I scoured the internet, HP forums, etc.

It seems to have no clear answer. Either they say that

> If the system board was replaced, branding on the unit is not been done properly,
> so branding needs to be done by HP certified technician. So, contact HP so that the system board can be replaced/reprogrammed.

My system board was not replaced. So this one is out.

> To fix it, all I did was turn Secure Boot back to "Enabled" in the Secure Boot Options in the BIOS.

This worked for one of my friend's Desktops  (with a similar configuration). Except that it had only a dual boot  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Q4 OS. Though he can't access the Q4 OS part once he turned on Secure boot.

Comment: Usually, not "committed" refers to a "dirty" partition, e.g. a Windows partition with hiberfil.sys and other files that are should not be altered, even when Windows OS is not in use.  Eliminate Windows Fast Boot in BIOS/UEFI, and turn off Hibernation in Windows OS.